# Sequelize Model with Association Order by

Tags: sequelize.js

i have try o find answers on github and in the documentation but i didn't see anything related, can we do a order in the association, example below:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 class User extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Email, {
     foreignKey: 'user_id',
     onDelete: 'CASCADE',
     order : [['createdAt', 'DESC']] <--------------------
   });
 }
};

User.init({
 id: {
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
 },
}, {
 sequelize,
 tableName: 'user',
});
return User;
};
```

Also can we set a default order on a Model??

Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: You can't set the order in the association itself but you can do it in the default scope (or a named one if you want to indicate it explicitly in a query)  that will be applied on a model in queries.

Comment: @Anatoly, you are saying is add a defaultScope to the UserEmail ?? or add this to User

 defaultScope: {
   include: [{
     model: sequelize.models.Email,
     order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
   }]
 }

Comment: Rather the second one

Comment: The ideia you give it works only when query is done on the model, if i try to do a query with association this dosne't work and dosen't respect the defaultScope from my Model Email

Comment: Can you try to indicate `Email.scope('your_scoep_name')` in the include option?